# Getting <span> text on web scraping

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer, jsdom

I'm using Puppeteer and jsDOM to scrape this site: https://www.lcfc.com/matches/results.

I want the names of the teams of every match, so on the console I use this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.match-item__team-container span')
  .forEach(element => console.log(element.textContent));
```

On the console, the names prints ok but when I use this on my code it returns nothing.

This is my code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const jsdom = require('jsdom');
(async () => {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch() ;
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const response = await page.goto('https://www.lcfc.com/matches/results');
    const body = await response.text();
    const { window: { document } } = new jsdom.JSDOM(body);

    document.querySelectorAll('.match-item__team-container span')
      .forEach(element => console.log(element.textContent));

    await browser.close();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
})();
```

And I don't have any error. Some suggestion? Thank you.

I tried with this code now, but still not working. I show the code and a picture of the console:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch() ;
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.waitForSelector('.match-item__team-container span');
    const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
      document.querySelectorAll('.match-item__team-container span')
          .forEach(element => console.log(element.textContent));
    });
    //listen to console events in the chrome tab and log it in nodejs process
    page.on('console', consoleObj => console.log(consoleObj.text()));

    await browser.close();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
})();
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do it puppeter way and use `evaluate` to run your code after waiting for the selector to appear via `waitForSelector`

```js
await page.waitForSelector('.match-item__team-container span');
const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.match-item__team-container span')
      .forEach(element => console.log(element.textContent));
    //or return the values of the selected item
   return somevalue; 
});
//listen to console events in the chrome tab and log it in nodejs process
page.on('console', consoleObj => console.log(consoleObj.text()));
```

`evaluate` runs your code inside the active tab of the chrome so you will not need `jsDOM` to parse the response.

**UPDATE**
The new timeout issue is because the page is taking too long to load: use `{timeout : 0}`

```js
const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.match-item__team-container span')
      .forEach(element => console.log(element.textContent));
    //or return the values of the selected item
   return somevalue; 
},{timeout:60000});
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. Can you expand the code? Because I don't know if I missing something because I'm new on Puppeter

Comment: @iMSn20 you weren't getting anything because `console.log` inside `evaluate` is not in your nodejs process' context. I have updated code with a listener that should log the console response to your terminal

Comment: I have to remove the `const` on `const await page.evaulate` because the code expected an `','` on page.evaluate() or add a const name to that part.

Comment: @iMSn20 that's fine, I missed declaring a variable, updated the code. Are you now getting console.log()?

Comment: No, still not working. I edited the question with more information if u need. Ty!

Comment: @iMSn20 although I have updated the answer for the new issue but please don't update the same question with new issue when existing one is solved. Appropriate will be to accept the answer if it solved the issue and open a new question for new issue

Comment: Oh, sry but I think is the same problem, because I see my first code wasn't showing any error because I wasn't printing them. That's why I update the question. Again, I'm sorry! And the updated answer doesn't solve the problem!

Comment: I will advise you checking complete API list of Puppeter here https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md and checking some in details. That way you will have a general idea. Website loading is an async task and there are timeouts for every methods even `goto`,`newPage` etc which you can manage via options

Comment: @iMSn20 what did you get on increasing the timeout? you should take your connection speed and page rendering speed into account when setting the timeout value